# Android: PageTransformer applying correct scale but not alpha before first touch

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `PageTransformer` that correctly displays my `ViewPager` with the second element correctly scaled, but there is no alpha applied to the second element. However, upon dragging the `ViewPager` a miniscule amount, the next view is properly displayed. The code for both my alpha and scale is identical, I'm not sure what the issue here is.

I have tried calling code from a handler once the `ViewPagerAdapter` has things added to it (such as `viewPager.scrollBy()` and `pager.beginFakeDrag()`) but these didn't help.

`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` is set. I have tried setting alpha to the views programmatically when instantiated in the `Adapter` but it has no effect. If the scale is correctly being applied then the alpha should be as well, surely.

```
@Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position)
    {
        float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
        float alphaFactor = Math.max(MIN_ALPHA, 1 - Math.abs(position));

        page.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        page.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        page.setAlpha(alphaFactor);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `android:animateLayoutChanges=true` set on the ViewPager. Once I removed this, it loaded correctly. Don't ask me why it was there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**(EDIT) CORRECT SOLUTION:**

Replace `ViewPager` with `ViewPager2`.

Useful resources:

- https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694887/10504386

**LAZY (AND NOT SO COOL, ERROR PRONE) SOLUTION:**

Unfortunately for me, I did not have the property `android:animateLayoutChanges=true` set in my layout.

I faced the same problem when I moved the `ViewPager` from an `Activity` to a `Fragment`.

I think the problem is due to the fact I reused the fragment. Upon a `FragmentTransaction`, the `ViewPager` technically still has its old value, so its view doesn't need to change, that's why the `PageTransformer` isn't fired.

Basically, all you need to do is to set the `ViewPager`'s `currentItem` to `0`, and then set it to the value you want to.

This is my snippet (`MyViewPager.kt`, but you don't need to override `ViewPager`).

```
init {
    post {
        currentItem = 0
    }
}


fun setCurrentPage(position: Int) {
    post {
        setCurrentItem(position, true) // I want smooth scroll
    }
}
```