# Android ViewPager2 setPageMargin unresolved

Tags: android, carousel, android-viewpager2

I want to implement Carousel using **`View Pager2`** with preview of left and right page like this:

[image]

Initially I was using view pager1 which supported. Now I think it's removed

```
    viewPagerhost.setPageMargin(20);
```

Any idea how we can achieve this using View Pager 2

Comment: there is an issue created at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132249311

Comment: Please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67771069/3586084

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Now we need to use `setPageTransformer()` in [**`Version 1.0.0-alpha05`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha05)

> New features

- `ItemDecorator` introduced with a behaviour consistent with RecyclerView.
- `MarginPageTransformer` introduced to provide an ability to create space between pages (outside of page inset).
- `CompositePageTransformer` introduced to provide an ability to combine multiple PageTransformers.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
myViewPager2.setPageTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(1500));
```

> Check out [my previous answer if you want to implement Carousel using View Pager2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58056129/7666442)

Comment: this doesn't create preview like OP asks, how is this even an answer ? it just widens the gap between pages.

Answer (score 41):

`MarginPageTransformer` cannot help your need.

You must use custom **setPageTrarnsformer**.

---

## Step 1

Here is my Extension Method for this.

you can check detail in this article
[Medium article](https://proandroiddev.com/look-deep-into-viewpager2-13eb8e06e419)

```
fun ViewPager2.setShowSideItems(pageMarginPx : Int, offsetPx : Int) {

    clipToPadding = false
    clipChildren = false
    offscreenPageLimit = 3

    setPageTransformer { page, position ->

        val offset = position * -(2 * offsetPx + pageMarginPx)
        if (this.orientation == ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL) {
            if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(this) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
                page.translationX = -offset
            } else {
                page.translationX = offset
            }
        } else {
            page.translationY = offset
        }
    }

}
```

### Step 2

set pageMarginPx and offsetPx with your use case.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="pageMargin">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pagerOffset">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pageMarginAndoffset">50dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

### Step 3

set your side margin of layout item in your xml.

like this

```xml
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pageMarginAndoffset"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/pageMarginAndoffset"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: That medium article is a godsend. All I had to do was convert it to java and it worked so simply. This is the better answer. To anyone overlooking this answer or the link, definitely give it a read. it saved me hours.

Comment: U save me with "ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(this) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL". its take 4 hours. thank man

Comment: This code is just a copy of the attached article. Anyway good job.

Comment: Use the below code inside setPageTransformer (), if you are not able to set marginLeft, marginRight via xml. Ex: In a merge layout.

page.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
            marginStart = 100
            marginEnd =  100
        }

Comment: really nice solution, but in my case, the first and last item has a huge margin, and I am not sure on how to handle it, any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I used [MJ Studio's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694887/5004910) to create my custom `PageTransformer` that also changes the page margin as follows:

```
class OffsetPageTransformer(
    @Px private val offsetPx: Int,
    @Px private val pageMarginPx: Int
) : ViewPager2.PageTransformer {

    override fun transformPage(page: View, position: Float) {
        val viewPager = requireViewPager(page)
        val offset = position * -(2 * offsetPx + pageMarginPx)
        val totalMargin = offsetPx + pageMarginPx

        if (viewPager.orientation == ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL) {
            page.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
                marginStart = totalMargin
                marginEnd = totalMargin
            }

            page.translationX = if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(viewPager) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
                -offset
            } else {
                offset
            }
        } else {
            page.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
                topMargin = totalMargin
                bottomMargin = totalMargin
            }

            page.translationY = offset
        }
    }

    private fun requireViewPager(page: View): ViewPager2 {
        val parent = page.parent
        val parentParent = parent.parent
        if (parent is RecyclerView && parentParent is ViewPager2) {
            return parentParent
        }
        throw IllegalStateException(
            "Expected the page view to be managed by a ViewPager2 instance."
        )
    }
}
```

That way you can just call:

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(OffsetPageTransformer(offsetPx, pageMarginPx))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
   viewPager.setPageTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(margin as PX));
```

but if you want to use DP you can use the below function for convert PX to DP

```
 private  int pxToDp(int px) {
    return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MarginPageTransformer` helps to define spaces between pages.

`offscreenPageLimit` let you define how many pages should be rendered offscreen.

Sample of the code:

```
viewPager2.offscreenPageLimit = 3
viewPager2.setPageTransformer(MarginPageTransformer({MARGIN AS PX}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers if anyone is seeking to achieve a situation where the first item is only have a space in the right and the last item has space only in the left like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

apply this code to your viewpager2

```
viewPagerPhotos.apply {
    adapter = photosAdapter

    clipToPadding = false
    clipChildren = false
    offscreenPageLimit = 3

    val pageMargin = 16.dpToPx(this@MaintenanceCenterDetailsActivity)
    val offset = 24.dpToPx(this@MaintenanceCenterDetailsActivity)
    setPageTransformer { page, position ->
        val pageOffset = position * -(2 * offset + pageMargin)
        if (viewPagerPhotos.orientation == ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL) {
            if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(viewPagerPhotos) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
                page.translationX = -pageOffset
            } else {
                page.translationX = pageOffset
            }
        } else {
            page.translationY = pageOffset
        }
    }
}
```

then in your view holder you need to do the following

```
fun bind(photoUrl: String) {
    with(binding.root) {
        if (itemCount > 1) {
            updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
                when (layoutPosition) {
                    0 -> {
                        marginStart = 0
                        marginEnd = marginValue
                    }
                    itemCount - 1 -> {
                        marginStart = marginValue
                        marginEnd = 0
                    }
                    else -> {
                        marginStart = marginValue
                        marginEnd = marginValue
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        load(photoUrl) {
            crossfade(true)
        }
    }
}
```

here is the extension function that converts dp to px

```
fun Int.dpToPx(context: Context): Int {
    val resources = context.resources
    val scale = resources.displayMetrics.density
    return (this * scale).toInt()
}
```