# View Pager with previous and next item smaller in size with infinite scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-transitions, android-viewpager2

Want to create the view pager same as following UI, applied custom transformer but not working.

[image]

ViewPager.java

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
public static final String TAG = "MyViewPager";
private float MAX_SCALE = 0.0f;
private int mPageMargin;
private boolean animationEnabled=true;
private boolean fadeEnabled=false;
private  float fadeFactor=0.5f;


public MyViewPager(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // clipping should be off on the pager for its children so that they can scale out of bounds.
    setClipChildren(false);
    setClipToPadding(false);
    // to avoid fade effect at the end of the page
    setOverScrollMode(2);
    setPageTransformer(false, this);
    setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mPageMargin = dp2px(context.getResources(), 50);
    setPadding(mPageMargin, mPageMargin, mPageMargin, mPageMargin);
}

public int dp2px(Resources resource, int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, resource.getDisplayMetrics());
}
public void setAnimationEnabled(boolean enable) {
    this.animationEnabled = enable;
}

public void setFadeEnabled(boolean fadeEnabled) {
    this.fadeEnabled = fadeEnabled;
}

public void setFadeFactor(float fadeFactor) {
    this.fadeFactor = fadeFactor;
}

@Override
public void setPageMargin(int marginPixels) {
    mPageMargin = marginPixels;
// setPadding(mPageMargin, mPageMargin, mPageMargin, mPageMargin);
}

@Override
public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
    if (mPageMargin <= 0|| !animationEnabled)
        return;
    page.setPadding(mPageMargin / 3, mPageMargin / 3, mPageMargin / 3, mPageMargin / 3);

    if (MAX_SCALE == 0.0f && position > 0.0f && position < 1.0f) {
        MAX_SCALE = position;
    }
    position = position - MAX_SCALE;
    float absolutePosition = Math.abs(position);
    if (position <= -1.0f || position >= 1.0f) {
        if(fadeEnabled)
            page.setAlpha(fadeFactor);
        // Page is not visible -- stop any running animations

    } else if (position == 0.0f) {

        // Page is selected -- reset any views if necessary
        page.setScaleX((1 + MAX_SCALE));
        page.setScaleY((1 + MAX_SCALE));
        page.setAlpha(1);
    } else {
        page.setScaleX(1 + MAX_SCALE * (1 - absolutePosition));
        page.setScaleY(1 + MAX_SCALE * (1 - absolutePosition));
        if(fadeEnabled)
            page.setAlpha( Math.max(fadeFactor, 1 - absolutePosition));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo its not the duplicated both question are for different views

Comment: @NileshRathod I haven't found any proper solution, do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @mdDroid have you checked my below answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58056129/7666442

Comment: Please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67771069/3586084

Answer (score 21):

### UPDATE - if you want to make current page zoom use below `PageTransformer`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

public class JavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
    MyAdapter MyAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_java);

        myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        MyAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
        myViewPager2.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
        myViewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        float pageMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.pageMargin);
        float pageOffset = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.offset);

        myViewPager2.setPageTransformer((page, position) -> {
            float myOffset = position * -(2 * pageOffset + pageMargin);
            if (position < -1) {
                page.setTranslationX(-myOffset);
            } else if (position <= 1) {
                float scaleFactor = Math.max(0.7f, 1 - Math.abs(position - 0.14285715f));
                page.setTranslationX(myOffset);
                page.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
                page.setAlpha(scaleFactor);
            } else {
                page.setAlpha(0);
                page.setTranslationX(myOffset);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: ![enter image description here]

NOTE: you can download complete code from [my GitHub repositories](https://github.com/RathodNilesh14/carousel-layout-using-viewPager2)

Try this way

> JavaActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

public class JavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
    MyAdapter MyAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_java);

        myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        MyAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
        myViewPager2.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
        myViewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        float pageMargin= getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.pageMargin);
        float pageOffset = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.offset);
        
        myViewPager2.setPageTransformer(new ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
                float myOffset = position * -(2 * pageOffset + pageMargin);
                if (myViewPager2.getOrientation() == ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL) {
                    if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(myViewPager2) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
                        page.setTranslationX(-myOffset);
                    } else {
                        page.setTranslationX(myOffset);
                    }
                } else {
                    page.setTranslationY(myOffset);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> activity_java layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  tools:context=".JavaActivity">
    
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    
    </LinearLayout>

>
```

> MyAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvName.setText(String.format("Row number%d", position));
        if (position % 2 ==0){
            holder.imgBanner.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }else {
            holder.imgBanner.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 15;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName;
        ImageView imgBanner;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            imgBanner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBanner);
        }
    }
}
```

> row_item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pageMarginAndOffset"
             android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/pageMarginAndOffset"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Hello"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been trying to implement the carousel with `ViewPager2` for a few hours with no success.

Comment: I don't think that you need to set `clipToPadding="false"` on the `ViewPager` because it doesn't have any padding. Also, I don't think that you need `clipChildren="false"` either since you are not scaling any item more than 100% (ie. you're not drawing outside of the `ViewPager`). On your GitHub code nothing changes if I remove them. I'd suggest to remove this attributes if they are useless.

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo okay i will remove that

Comment: Another thing: you are setting `offscreenPageLimit` to 3. This means that there are 3 items retained on *each* side (total 6), even though you are only showing 1 extra item at each side. Unless you have the need to do so, you can lower this number to 2 or even 1 (everything keeps working fine).

Comment: somehow this is leaving empty blank space after some scrolling

Comment: Why does my page overlap each other? How to fix this issue

Comment: @MathematicsBeginner can you please share your code in git repo so I can take look into your issue

Comment: @AskNilesh Thanks. I got it. Adding padding to page layout solved my issue. Your answer really helpful! :D

Comment: @MathematicsBeginner happy to help you buddy

Comment: An explanation on what's happening would be nice. I don't like to just copy & paste...

Answer (score 13):

Using ViewPager2 (that has RecyclerView in it).

**vp2** is instance of **ViewPager2**

This worked for me:

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) vp2.getChildAt(0);
rv.setPadding(80, 0, 80, 0);
rv.setClipToPadding(false);
```

I used **FragmentStateAdapter** for it and overriding `getItemId()` and `containsItem()` for add/remove fragments.

result is here:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `clipToPadding` and programmatically adding the `pageMargin` and `padding` to your `viewpager`.
Try something like this-

```
viewpager.setClipToPadding(false);
viewpager.setPadding(40, 0, 70, 0);
viewpager.setPageMargin(20);
```

Comment: This code is related to ViewPager, OP is using ViewPager2