# ViewPager2 How to change no of full visible card item?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I am having a requirement with viewpager2 where on a portrait I need to show 1 full card and on the landscape, I need to make it 2 along with a showing of the previous and next card boundaries.
How Can I achieve it as it was easier to implement with viewpager but viewpager2 is not able to do?

Please suggest some workable solutions or alternatives to *getPageWidth()* we had in the pager where based on device orientation used to set page width size

Also, Page transforms margin and offset do not work until I am scrolling through the pager item The attached image is for portrait mode 1 full card whereas in the landscape I need 2 full card
[image: Viewpager in potrait],

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android ViewPager2 setPageMargin unresolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56114430/android-viewpager2-setpagemargin-unresolved)

Comment: No , i am looking for alernative of getPageWidth()